# Modeling a composite key of foreign keys (modelled as entity references) in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, entity-framework-6

I am coming from nHibernate and am trying to create an entity that has a 2 column composite key where both columns are also foreign keys.

For example I have a UserRole table that is (UserId Guid, RoleId Guid). I *want* to model this as

```
public class UserRole
{
  public User User { get; set; }
  public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

EF doesn't seem to like this idea though. It seems to want me to also add `Guid UserId {get;set;}` and `Guid RoleId { get; set; }`. I managed to resolve this for the handling the FK part by defining the model in the dbcontext like so:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Role)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("RoleId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("UserId"));
```

Which I hope I can turn into a convention. However when I tried to do this too:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.User, x.Role });
```

it craps out at runtime with:

```
The property 'User' cannot be used as a key property on the entity 'Paroxysm.Domain.UserRole' because the property type is not a valid key type. Only scalar types, string and byte[] are supported key types.
```

FYI this is done in nHibernate byCode mapping like this (slightly different example):

```
public class ProjectUserProfileMap : ClassMap<ProjectUserProfile>
{
    public ProjectUserProfileMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.User, "UserId")
            .KeyReference(x => x.Project, "ProjectId");

        ReadOnly();

        References(x => x.User, "UserId");
        References(x => x.Project, "ProjectId");

        Map(x => x.IsActive);
        Map(x => x.ActivatedUtcDate).Not.Nullable().CustomType<NHibernate.Type.UtcDateTimeType>();
        Map(x => x.InvitedUtcDate).Not.Nullable().CustomType<NHibernate.Type.UtcDateTimeType>();

        Table("ProjectUserProfile");
    }
}
```

So easy! Incidentally that little CustomType UTC behaviour doesn't seem to be supported by EF either.

Problem is not actually related to the fact that I have a composite key but having a single column PK which is also an FK would be a weird case (1:1 rel).

So I guess I want to know definitely if this can or cannot be done in EF6. The error message certainly indicates its not doable. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this but only if you add to UserRole 2 foreign key properties: RoleId and UserId. This is because HasKey do not offer any mapping functionality - it can be defined only on properties existing in entity classes. It seems EF enforces that all Primary Key columns are always defined as concrete properties in classes wheres foreign key columns may not have corresponding properies defined. So to achieve what you want you need to define UserRole like this:

```
public class UserRole
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Role)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.RoleId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.User)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal()
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
```

The exact situation as you posted you might alternatively achieve by many-to-many relationship:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Roles)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(m => 
        { 
            m.ToTable("UserRole"); 
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId"); 
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId"); 
        });
```

With this you would achieve UserRole table with primary key defined on UserId and RoleId.

Comment: OK that's what I thought I'd have to do. Its a shame. Thanks